# Can an out-of-court settlement that includes an NDA prohibit disclosure of illegal activity?

Tags: non-disclosure, settlement

Can this stipulation be legal and enforceable?

Comment: This _probably_ varies by jurisdiction, so you'd likely want to include a specific jurisdiction in your question.

Comment: There are countries that don't allow NDAs at all.

Comment: It is in the State of California, County of Los Angeles.

Comment: The linked question, while relaed, is not a duplicate. The linked question is about the victiom being **required** to sign and adhere to an NDA. This is about a case where a victim chooses to accept an NDA as part of a settlement.